# test a specific string with regex

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i'm going to test a string of the form dd / mm / yyyy xx-xxxx-x xxx-xxx with a string array, i use to define the regex form but i think the format is not correctly declare

```
Regex rgx1 = new Regex(@"^d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\t[A-Z]\d{2}\-\d{4}\-\[A-Z0-9]\d{1}\t[A-Z]\d{3}\-\[A-Z]\d{3}$");
Match FormatS = rgx1.Match(tab[i]);

if ( FormatS.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tab[i]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can you supply example input that isn't working? We don't know what `tab[i]` contains... also: your "of the form" includes whitespace, but your regex doesn't. This would be a lot better if you had `string input = "..."; // your actual input here!`, and used `input` in place of `tab[i]` throughout - then we might stand a chance of helping you more

Comment: tab[i] is a table of string ..i need a whitespace between dd / mm / yyyy and xx-xxxx-x .that's way i make \t ..it's wrong!!!

Comment: side note: is this as simple as `\[` -> `[` in a few places?

Comment: "tab[i] is a table of string ." - yes, but without an **actual** example of a string that you think should work (i.e. be a match to the regex), it is **very hard to help you**; you can always change it back to the table (`tab[i]`) once it works :)

Comment: sorry..i don't undrestand

Comment: also, you might mean `^\d` instead of `^d` at the start (but please please provide a sample input!)

Comment: my project was to select data fields from file.csv and to make their in tab[i] then to check every data in tab[i]

Comment: "my project was to select data fields ..." - noted, but right now all we need to do is get the regex working; for *that*, it *doesn't matter* what you're using it for; all we need is an example string that you think should work, and which isn't actually working - all I'm asking for here is something like: "my input that isn't working correctly is `"13/02/2019 aa-1234-b CCD-942"`." - that's what we really need here

Comment: yes it is a already an exemple for test like 16/09/2018 BJ-5043-5 TUN-KLG

Comment: Perfect; and with that: we can help! see below

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment with sample input, this works:

```
Regex rgx1 = new Regex(@"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-[A-Z0-9]{1}\s[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}$");
```

Problems I found:

- `\[` instead of `[` in two places
- `d` instead of `\d` at the start
- `\t` instead of `\s` (or just a space would probably be fine, too)
- a few unnecessary `\d`

I also removed a few unnecessarily-escaped tokens, but... those don't matter as much.

Comment: `Regex rgx1 = new Regex(@"^d{2}\/d{2}\/d{4}\[A-Z]d{2}\-d{4}\-\[A-Z0-9]d{1}\[A-Z]d{3}\-\[A-Z]d{3}$");` is that correct now!!

Comment: @Amani no; you've dropped the leading slash in `\d` in a few places, and you're using `\[` when you mean `[`. And you probably don't want the `d` *at all* in some of those places (`\[A-Z]d{3}` should probably be `[A-Z]{3}`, for example). The example I provided works... yours looks nothing like that

Comment: thanks Marc ..can you please correct all the regex because i dont understand when i put \d and i put d